# How to send json data from go to dart

Tags: flutter, dart, go

```
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

type userStruct struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

//export GetData
func GetData() userStruct {
    fmt.Println("hi from go")
    user := userStruct{name: "RK", age: 22}
    return user
}
```

how can I call the GetData function in dart? since we can't use go structs in c-shared libraries. My goal is to send data of any kind like bytes, maps, structs etc.. from go to dart. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: use json to convert

Comment: Use some framework like gorilla mux or fiber